# How to configure InvokeHTTP processor for HTTPS?

Tags: apache-nifi

So I am trying to make GET request and as Remote URL  I am using [this open api endpoint.](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=IBM&interval=5min&apikey=demo)

But InvokeHTTP processor shows an error: `Unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

So since I am new to nifi I didn't touch any other setting.
Can someone please help me with proper configuration for this?

Thank you beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `SSL Context Service` property (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ssl-context-service-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardSSLContextService/index.html) in the `InvokeHTTP` processor